# Is there a word or phrase for "promises that can't be kept"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I know that [renege](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/renege#:%7E:text=To%20renege%20is%20to%20go,what%20you%20said%20you%20would.)
is a word that could suit in here. But as I understand, 'renege' describes the failure to keep a promise.

But, sometimes, we make promises that we know all too well that it can't be kept for long. Is there any word or a phrase for such promises?.

Answer (score 36):

You are describing an **[empty promise](https://www.lexico.com/definition/empty_promise)**, which is a promise that will not be kept. It doesn't directly describe the timeframe in which the promise is broken, but an empty promise will usually not be fulfilled at all.

Comment: This answer should note that “empty promise” focuses on the fact that the promise *will not* be kept—not that it *could not* be kept.

Comment: Agreed with KRyan. "Empty promise" has a connotation where it was made when the maker has no intention or expectation to fulfill the promise, whereas the question is regarding a promise made when the maker is _unable_ to fulfill it. A subtle but important distinction.

Comment: @Abion47 IMO it fits here. If you knowingly make a promise you cannot keep, it's an empty promise. Especially in the context of "cannot keep it for long", that suggests it's too difficult to choose to keep it, not that it's literally impossible.

Answer (score 14):

In the movie Mary Poppins, Mary refers to such promises as "Pie crust promises".  "Easily made, easily broken".

> Michael:   Will you stay if we promise to be good?

> Mary Poppins:   Och! That's a piecrust promise. Easily made, easily broken.

Comment: Not a lot of tokens on Google, but too good to downvote.

Answer (score 8):

**false promise**

> A promise that is made with no intention of carrying it out and
> especially with intent to deceive or defraud [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promise)

---

> Now it might be said that the moral rigorism involved in the view that
> we ought never, in any circumstances, to make **false promises**, tell
> lies or break promises is just a personal idiosyncrasy of Kant's, and
> that we do not have to treat it as an integral part of his moral
> philosophy...It is one thing to argue that if everyone made **false
> promises** whenever they thought it to their advantage there could be
> no such thing as a promise... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reason_Action_and_Morality/YRswEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20a%20false%20promise%22&pg=PT111&printsec=frontcover).

> A **promise is false**, not by virtue of not making promise, but by
> virtue of not doing the relevant things subsequently. Hence a **false
> promise** is a case of a promise. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Collected_Writings_of_Jaysankar_Lal/dbnMDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20a%20false%20promise%22&pg=PA200&printsec=frontcover).

> The gravamen of Ms. Tarmann's complaint was that the defendant insurer
> made a **false promise** to pay for car repairs upon their completion a
> future event. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/California_Court_of_Appeal_2nd_Appellate/fmvBCvv9EU8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22made%20a%20false%20promise%22&pg=PA14&printsec=frontcover).

There is a **bad faith promise** in law:

> A bad faith promise remains an effective promise “but it is not a lie
> or a misstatement.” [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Without_Alibi/lkrqxmaQaDsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bad%20faith%20promise&pg=PA291&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: I don't think you can separate "bad faith statement" from "lie". They are almost synonyms. If something is done in bad faith, it is a deliberate deception.

Comment: For all intents and purposes I agree. However, I think there are linguistic and truth-condition nuances. If I make a promise in bad faith, but then keep it (for whatever reason), it may have been made in bad faith, but at least in one sense it wasn't a lie. However, it does meet the requirement:  (1) it was made in the form of a  promise and (2) there was no intention of keeping it

Comment: This answer has the same problem as "empty promise" where it means the maker has no intention of keeping the promise, not that they _couldn't_ keep the promise.

Comment: Yes  false promises can be that, but others may be **disingenuous promises** that turn out to be false because they were indeed broken. If I had to write an answer from scratch, *disingenuous promises* might be a better fit. It also has to do with "can't be kept" -- actual impossibility or likelihood?

Answer (score 6):

If you make a promise you know you cannot keep, the word for that is *lie*.

I'm not entirely satisfied with this because *lie* is a broader category; not every lie is a promise, other than in the *guarantee* (a fact) nuance of *promise* which appears in *I promise you that this is true*.

However, it's usually clear from context that a reference to some *lie* is actually about a bad faith promise, rather than some other lie, such as a cover-up of events or failed responsibilities.

I suspect that there might not exist a single verb which we can fill in for

> Bob ____ed that he will return the money

where where *____ed* specifically means *lied as he promised*.

However, note that in an example like this we do not need such a verb, because the complement "that he will return the money" establishes the context that a promise is being made, allowing us to just use the verb *to lie*:

> Bob lied that he will return the money.

Comment: Perhaps a *white* lie?

Comment: @Tim absolutely not.  A white lie is a lie made with good intentions.  An intention to break a promise is not a good one.

Comment: @Simon It can still be a white lie. E.g. telling your doctor that you'll improve your diet, to get them to stop bugging you about it. You know that you won't be able to keep it up for long.

Comment: @Barmar That's not really a promise; it's more like a resolution or pledge made in front of the doctor. Your doctor cares about you professionally, but ultimately knows it's just up to you and doesn't care that way.

Comment: @Barmar that’s not a white lie. The intention is to deceive your doctor.  It doesn’t become a good intention just because it benefits the liar!

Comment: @Simon What about when you promise a dying child that you will save them while knowing full well that they are doomed no matter what?

Comment: We’ve established that not every empty promise is a white lie. I don’t think categorising every possible lie is on topic here.

Comment: White lies don't have to be noble. Telling someone something untrue to avoid a minor embarrassment is a white lie.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody who commits or attempts to do something they can't succeed at can be said to have **bitten off more than they can chew**.

Comment: I think this is one of those "similar area, which makes it all the more wrong". BOMTYCC generally means there's too much work and you won't be able to finish. The Q seems more like "I'll change the babies diapers" -- you can do it, but definitely won't.

Comment: This implies that the person who made the promise really wanted to keep it, but couldn't. Not what OP is asking.

Comment: @OwenReynolds The question asks about when a promise is made with the knowledge that it can't be kept. It doesn't make any assumptions on whether the promise was made maliciously or with good intentions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a standing expression, but instead of the term "impossible promise" which implies that there isn't a point to an attempt of keeping it, a possibly better fit may be "doomed promise" to indicate that it won't likely progress to the state of fulfillment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just go with overcommit / overcommitment.

"To bind or obligate (oneself, for example) beyond the capacity for realization."

It isn't limited by whether or not the committer knew it was unrealizable, only that it was.  It could be qualified as "knowingly overcommit" where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Variations on *don't write a cheque that you can't cash*.

[Quora, referencing Top Gun](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-Your-mouth-is-writing-a-check-that-the-rest-of-your-body-cant-cash-mean).

> Stinger (the aircraft carrier commander) tells Maverick, "Son, your ego is writing checks your body can't cash."

Or, [Don't write checks your body can't cash](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dont-write-checks-your-body-cant-cash.1941912/)

The "mouth/ego" writing part and the "body" cashing part don't matter all that much here.  **Something** *writes a cheque*, i.e. makes a commitment, and *can't cash it*, i.e. what was promised could not possibly be delivered.

Urban Dictionary has a more [colorful variation](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Your%20mouth%20is%20writing%20checks%20your%20ass%20can%27t%20cash) on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single word for "promises that can't be kept".  So the next best thing is a phrase:

> transient promises

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/transient):

> transient (adjective)
>
> 1. not lasting, enduring, or permanent; transitory.
> 2. lasting only a short time; existing briefly; temporary: transient authority.
> 3. staying only a short time: the transient guests at a hotel.

Answer (score -1):

### False Pretenses:

false pre·​tens·​es | \ -ˈpre-ˌten-səz, -pri-ˈten- \
Legal Definition of false pretenses
: false representations concerning past or present facts that are made with the intent to defraud another
also : the crime of obtaining title to another's property by false pretenses
From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/false%20pretenses#:%7E:text=%3A%20false%20representations%20concerning%20past%20or,by%20trick%20at%20larceny%2C%20theft)

This is similar to a [false premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_premise), depending on how it is used and the level of culpability. Check out the [synonyms](https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-synonyms/false+premise#:%7E:text=1%20concocted%2C%20erroneous%2C%20faulty%2C,unsound%2C%20untrue%2C%20untrustworthy%2C%20untruthful) if one works better for you. I like "concocted" personally.

Comment: That's just legalese verbiage. Can there be "true pretenses"? Merriam-Webster also gives one definition of "pretense" as "false appearance or action intended to deceive"; the "false" is built into "pretense".  It's pretty much just a synonym of "sham", "deception", and such."The crime of obtaining title to another's property by lying" works just fine.

Comment: @Kaz I'm not disagreeing, but English is full of this stuff, and it seemed the closest match I could find to "I know it's physically impossible for my lie to ever be true."

Answer (score -4):

Impossible promises or not possible to keep promises

Comment: Impossible promise works, not sure about the other.  Could you perhaps show an example?